# How add custom params at XYZ url request?

Tags: openlayers

OpenLayers does a great job on requesting tiles to a given XYZ server.

What if I need to append extra params (let's say datetime) to those auto-calculated Tiles:

https://tile.server.com/streets/tiles/256/14/8024/6176?access_token=.....**&datetime=1000**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could add extra parameters in either a `tileUrlFunction` or `tileLoadFunction`, e.g.

```
tileLoadFunction: function(imageTile, src) {
  imageTile.getImage().src = src + '&datetime=1000';
},
```